# SWIG Converting Python list to a char ** example fails

Tags: python, c++, swig, swig-typemap

I am following the SWIG tutorial and I'm currently on the section: "[32.9.1 Converting Python list to a char **](http://www.swig.org/Doc4.0/SWIGDocumentation.html#Python_nn59)". The example in question returns a malloc error on my machine:

```
import example  
example.print_args(["a","bc","dc"])
```

> python(57911,0x10bd32e00) malloc: *** error for object 0x7f7ee0406b90: pointer being freed was not allocated
> python(57911,0x10bd32e00) malloc: *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
> [1](http://www.swig.org/Doc4.0/SWIGDocumentation.html#Python_nn59)    57911 abort      python
> [1](http://www.swig.org/Doc4.0/SWIGDocumentation.html#Python_nn59)    57911 abort      python

The error is unexpected as this is exactly the code that the tutorial offers. Any help welcome! Thanks in advance

Specs:

- MacOS Big Sur
- Python 3.8
- C++17

Here are my setup.py (the whole [archive](https://easyupload.io/ll7lee) for reproducibility):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

"""
setup.py file for SWIG example
"""

from distutils.core import setup, Extension
import os
import sys
import glob

# gather up all the source files
srcFiles = ['example.i']
includeDirs = []

srcDir = os.path.abspath('src')
for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(srcDir):
    for dirname in dirnames:
        absPath = os.path.join(root, dirname)
        globStr = "%s/*.c*" % absPath
        files = glob.glob(globStr)
        includeDirs.append(absPath)
        srcFiles += files

extra_args = ['-stdlib=libc++', '-mmacosx-version-min=10.7', '-std=c++17', '-fno-rtti']
os.environ["CC"] = 'clang++'
#
example_module = Extension('_example',
                           srcFiles,  # + ['example.cpp'], # ['example_wrap.cxx', 'example.cpp'],
                           include_dirs=includeDirs,
                           swig_opts=['-c++'],
                           extra_compile_args=extra_args,
                           )

setup(name='example',
      version='0.1',
      author="SWIG Docs",
      description="""Simple swig example from docs""",
      ext_modules=[example_module],
      py_modules=["example"],
      )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example code would work with Python 2, but has a bug as well as a syntax change for Python 3.  `char**` must be passed byte strings, which are the default in Python 2 when using `"string"` syntax, but need a leading `b`, e.g. `b"string"` in Python 3.

This works:

```py
import example  
example.print_args([b"a",b"bc",b"dc"])
```

The crash is due to a bug calling `free` twice if an incorrect parameter type is found.  Make the following change to the example:

```c
      if (PyString_Check(o)) {
        $1[i] = PyString_AsString(PyList_GetItem($input, i));
      } else {
        //free($1); // REMOVE THIS FREE
        PyErr_SetString(PyExc_TypeError, "list must contain strings");
        SWIG_fail;
```

`SWIG_fail;` ends up called the `freearg` typemap, which calls free a second time.  With this change, you should see the following if passing incorrect arguments, such as a non-list or  Unicode strings instead of byte strings:

```py
>>> import argv
>>> argv.print_args(1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\argv.py", line 66, in print_args
    return _argv.print_args(argv)
TypeError: not a list
>>> argv.print_args(['abc','def'])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\argv.py", line 66, in print_args
    return _argv.print_args(argv)
TypeError: list must contain strings
>>> argv.print_args([b'abc',b'def'])
argv[0] = abc
argv[1] = def
2
```

Changing the error message to "list must contain *byte* strings" would help as well

Comment: Thanks Mark. That fixed it. Do you mind if I use your reply to propose an update to the documentation? I think the SWIG maintainers would be happy with it.

Comment: @Guillaume Go ahead.  There are probably lots of examples that have Python 2/3 differences, but the double-free bug is definitely something to fix.